# Blender Model Resizing after being Parented to Rig

Tags: objects, rigging, import, weight-painting, parent

I am working on rigging a character in blender but have been running into an issue.  Whenever I parent with automatic weights the mesh to the armature, my mesh scales drastically (scale of 10+).

I've taken the following troubleshooting steps:

- Ensure the origin of the mesh is at (0, 0, 0)
- Apply all transformations to the mesh (location, rotation, and scale) with ctrl + a
- Tried with both the rig generated from the Rigify add-on and a custom-made base rig, both of which exhibit the same issue

The mesh was imported from a .obj format from a model I bought online for a video project.  I've heard that there could be a potential problem here, if the base units between the program that made the file and blender differ.  However, I don't know how to check/fix this.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

Sincerely,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you would prefer a better solution, but: I know that .stl import has an option to use scene units, and it works for that format, helps sometimes to solve problems like this.

So maybe you could try to import the .obj, export in .stl, and then import the .stl using that option (or not, depending if any of the two fits).

Works since 2.73, afaik.

Comment: Does this preserve UV Maps and/or materials?

Comment: I dont' know but I guess not. As a workaround, if it works for the mesh, you can later assign materials/uv from the imported obj to the imported stl, perhaps. It is easy to make objects to share materials. But I don't know what you have, if the object is multimaterial, use vertex groups to assign different materials. And there is an add onto copy/paste UVs (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Copy_Paste_UVs). Probably not ideal for a production workflow, but doable for a one time job...

Comment: The stl export and import doesn't preserve the vertex count, so I'm having some trouble with this method.

Comment: That could easily be... you could try some other export formats (like collada, 3ds or fbx or else) since some of them have scale import options similar to stl. 

And I would also fill a bug (or ask a feature) to add a similar option to obj import...